# Two-way binding and background update does not re-render component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side project, where I have a custom component that uses a viewmodel to bind to inputbase checkbox.

If I change the viewmodel by clicking on a button, everything works fine.
But if I change the viewmodel by something more "background", like a GRPC push message, then the inputbase checkbox is not re-rendered.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the reason for a change is something related to UI, like a click of a button, an input change in a field, etc., in most cases, the render cycle is kicked off by Blazor.

However, if the reason is something more nested like a timer or a finished asynchronous call, you can use the method `StateHasChanged` in a component to trigger a new render cycle.

As mentioned in the comment, there might be drawbacks when this method is called outside the UI thread.  `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` helps to mitigate the issue. Besides, it is async like nearly which is more Blazor "serverish".

Comment: Depending on when and how you call it, it might be better to use `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` - this will be 1) async as all server-side blazor is and 2) will run the method in the context of the main (UI) thread so it has effect, otherwise if the caller is on another thread it may even throw.

Comment: Thanks, @rdmptn for pointing this out. I've updated the answer.